# How to create Data Flow Graph on Java

Tags: java, eclipse, plugins

I'm an engineering student, i studied data flow graph. I already made parser of java file.

I still working on data flow graph  how to make data flow graph .

I couldn't find tool and plug

I looking for data flow graph suing  java program plug-in or opensource code using eclipse.

Comment: I am interested in this as well. There is some work done already which results are Eclipse plugins: [Crystal](http://code.google.com/p/crystalsaf/), [Soot](http://www.bodden.de/2008/09/22/soot-intra/), and [JTest](http://www.parasoft.com/jsp/products/jtest.jsp) (the latter seems to be a commercial product). There is an Eclipse package org.eclipse.jdt.internal.corext.refactoring.code.flow but I can't find any corresponding documentation. It would be nice if there is some description on how it performs analysis and how to use the API.

Answer (score 0):

Standing at 2020, I still failed to find a decent tool for data flow graph generation, but here are several resources that might help:

1. Data Flow Analysis Using Soot:

[http://www.cs.toronto.edu/~aamodkore/notes/dfa-tutorial.html](http://www.cs.toronto.edu/%7Eaamodkore/notes/dfa-tutorial.html)

2. An open source project to generate data flow graph from classes:

https://github.com/daanvdh/JavaDataFlow